# On the Taylor series of the logarithm of the Riemann zeta function.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta

For $\Re(s)>1$, the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ is defined by

$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s},$$

or equivalently by the Euler product

$$\zeta(s) = \prod_{p} (1-p^{-s})^{-1}, $$

where $p$ runs over the entire set of primes. My question is, what is the Taylor series of $\log \zeta(s)$ ?

Comment: What's the Taylor Series of $\log\left[1 + \left(\zeta(s) - 1 \right) \right]$?

Comment: Perhaps you could try to take the Taylor series of $\log(x)$ and put the Taylor series of $\zeta(s)$ inside it followed by lots of expansions.

Comment: The Taylor series of $\log \zeta(s)$ around what $s$ ? if it is around $s_0, Re(s_0) > 1$ then  $$\log \zeta(s_0+s) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty s^k \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{p^m} \frac{p^{-s_0 m} (-\ln p^m)^k}{m}$$ with radius of convergence at least $Re(s_0) - 1$